# Creating a dynamic install directory in WiXSharp

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wixsharp

I am having trouble with with my directories, I want my InstallDir to be my top parent directory and for any other Dir to be contained within this folder structure. I have tried this multiple ways and can't seem to work it out but what I am aiming for is to be able to use the installDirDialog to change the install location. The directory left unchanged installs correctly, but if i was to change the install location it only builds the new folder structure and the files install install to the default location.  I know why it's installing to this location because its referencing a static string, I only used the below as an example to simplify the problem I am having.

```
string dirs = @"%ProgramFiles%\My Company\My Product";
var project = new ManagedProject("MyProduct",
   new InstallDir(dirs),        
   new Dir(dirs + @"\DataAPI",
       new Files(@"E:\Temp\installertemp\DataAPI\*.*")));
```

Another approach was to use an MSI property and set that as the install path.

```
public class General
    {
        public static string Product = "PRODUCT";
        public static string InstallLocation = "INSTALLDIRECTORY";
    }
```

In setup.cs
`string dirs = General.InstallLocation;`

I then set this property in the install dialog. 
`MsiRuntime.Session[General.InstallLocation] = installDir.Text;`

This didn't work either and only passed INSTALLDIRECTORY as the path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After countless hours wasted the solution was actually very simple and made clear to me by the kind folks over at [Wixsharp](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/issues/516).

Simply move the end bracket of instalDir to include any children Dirs and their files.

```
 new InstallDir(dirs,        
   new Dir("DataAPI",
       new Files(@"E:\Temp\installertemp\DataAPI\*.*")));
```